# MS Access crashing

Tags: ms-access, crash, dropdownbox

MS Access occasionally (once or twice a day) crashes when a value is selected from a drop-down list.  I have put diagnostic code under the AfterUpdate event (there is no code under any other event), but the crash appears to be occurring either at the declaration line (Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset, Conn As New ADODB.Connection, SQL As String) or the fact that an item is selected – if any code in the event is run, something will be written into the diagnostic table.

**Notes:**

Database is 2000 format although the user is running .mdb on Office 2013 – Full version ofAaccess

Back end database: SQL

Dropdown Rowsource: passthru query created before the form opens which returns six columns.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the rest of your code within those events please.

Comment: crash means? does it freeze? or just closes itself?

Comment: Is the access file on the local machine, or on a network drive?  Might be dropped network packets as they cause all sorts of mysterious issues/crashes

Comment: Are other items dependent on the value in that combobox? i.e does that value cascade?